# MS Graph SDK: Adding Parameters to CalendarView

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following statement in Graph Rest API that returns all events from a certain calendar within the given DateTime:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendars/ID/calendarView?startDateTime=2017-02-01T10:31:37Z&endDateTime=2017-02-10T10:31:37Z`

How would I do this using the SDK? What I got so far:

`ICalendarEventsCollectionPage retrievedEvent = await graphClient.Me.Calendars[id].CalendarView...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add these as QueryOptions to the request.

```
    QueryOption startDateTime = new QueryOption("startDateTime", "2017-02-01T10:31:37Z");
    QueryOption endDateTime = new QueryOption("endDateTime", "2017-02-10T10:31:37Z");
    List options = new List();
    options.Add(startDateTime);
    options.Add(endDateTime);

    ICalendarCalendarViewCollectionPage retrievedEvents = await graphClient
                                                                .Me
                                                                .Calendars["id"]
                                                                .CalendarView
                                                                .Request(options)
                                                                .GetAsync();
```

Comment: This is good. Thanks. But what if you also want to limit the events to one or two extended propert values too?

Comment: You are looking to add a filter statement? You can add a filter option like this:
    ...
    .Request(options)
    .Filter("name eq 'Contoso'"))
    .GetAsync();

Comment: I ended up using the `Events` instead of the `CalendarView`. According to the documentation the `CalendarView` can't be used with the `Filter` mechanism. But my problem is sorted now. Thanks.